# Loading icon using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to show ajax-loader.gif while data is loading, and after data is loaded completely, hide it.

Code `update`:

```
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
url: "api/Employee/GetData",
beforeSend: function () {
    // before send, show the loading gif
    $('#wait').show();
},
success: function (msg) {
    $.getJSON(uri).done(function (data) {

        $.each(msg, function (key, item) {
            // alert(item);
            $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#tbdata"));
        });
    });
    /* or simply put here each statement inside callback like so          
     $.each( msg, function (key, item) {
      // alert(item);
      $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#tbdata"));
     });
    */
    // or just hide here on success
    $('#wait').hide();
},
complete: function () {
    // or hide here
    // this callback called either success or failed
    $('#wait').hide();
}
}).done(function (data) {
$.each(data, function (key, item) {
    // alert(item);
    $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#tbdata"));
});
});
```

According to some answers, Ajax has start and stop functions as shown here:

```
$('#wait').ajaxStart(function() {
$(this).show();
}).ajaxComplete(function() {
$(this).hide();
});
```

My question is how to combine both codes in order to show and hide ajax-loader.gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` should be attached on document. Must be noted that, any ajax call will affected if you are using the global start and complete like you did. Anyway you can do like this :

```
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
     $('#wait').show();
  });
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#wait').hide();
  });
```

Other than that you can use `beforeSend` and `complete` **[AJAX setting properties](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)** , IMHO latter code much more prefer than former since the latter code affected to it request only while former affected another ajax request if you have more than that :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json', 
    url: "api/Employee/GetData",
    beforeSend : function () {  
       // before send, show the loading gif
       $('#wait').show(); 
    },
    success: function ( msg ) { 
      /* or simply put here each statement inside callback like so          
       $.each( msg, function (key, item) {
        // alert(item);
        $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#tbdata"));
       });
      */ 
      // or just hide here on success
       $('#wait').hide();
    },
    complete : function () { 
     // or hide here
     // this callback called either success or failed
     $('#wait').hide();
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
       // alert(item);
        $('<tr>', { html: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($("#tbdata"));
    });
});
```

Comment: so what shall I do in success function? do I need to get `json uri` and then append data to table and ignore `done` function ?

Comment: You can put them inside success callback, or just chaining at the end of ajax closing parentheses. See updated answer

Comment: can not append data and the image is not shown at all.

Comment: you can see update code and tell me where is my mistake, I have repeated appending in order to understand why no data append into table

Comment: Inside success callback no need for this `$.getJSON(uri).done(function (data) {..`.. just put $.each statement like my written comment. And try console.log(msg). see the data actually come out or not

Comment: it repeats data twice and image is not displayed !

Comment: Put back `formatItem` function inside post, wanna see that. and image loading do show maybe the request too fast. Try comment `$('#wait').hide();` inside success and complete callback both

Comment: you are right, request is too fast, how to delay that?

Comment: `it repeats data twice and image is not displayed` data twice because you have two callback for success. Remove either `.done(function()..` or `success : function (){`... You know that, `done` obj will called if request is success, same for success callback.

Comment: You can put hide code inside setTimeout function together with $.each statement for about 1 minutes or else.